# Django Rest Framework and Heroku - Error 401

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-401

I just deployed my website on Heroku, an integral part of the functionality of the site is to receive post requests from another website of mine. I'm using DRF's TokenAuthentication for my authentication. In my local environment everything works perfectly, but the same cannot be said for the live website. Whenever I send a POST request I receive a 401 error, the new token is added to the request's header and the data is exactly the same as the data used in the local environment. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

**views.py**

```
class PetCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PetSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if Breed.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.POST.get('breed_name', None)).exists():
            pass
        else:
            Breed.objects.create( breed_name=self.request.POST.get('breed_name', None),
                                  size=self.request.POST.get('size', None),
                                  temperament=self.request.POST.get('temperament', None),
                                  energy=self.request.POST.get('energy', None),
                                  hypoallergenic=self.request.POST.get('hypoallergenic', None))

        breed = Breed.objects.get(breed_name=self.request.POST.get('breed_name', None))
        # Assigns a groomer the created Pet
        groomer = assign_groomer(breed)
        serializer.save(groomer=groomer, breed=breed)

        SpaReport.objects.create(breed=breed, groomer=groomer)
```

**settings.py**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'bootstrap3',
    'captcha',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'django_celery_results',
    'mathfilters',
    'storages',
    'account',
    'sales',
    'scrty',
    'analytics'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pettracker.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'scrty.context_processors.from_settings',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pettracker.wsgi.application'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Comment: did you set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It is currently set to match anything.

Comment: What do your logs say? (You can check with `heroku logs`). And HTTP 401 simply means "unauthorized". Are you sure you're using a valid token that exists in your production database?